# iOS webapp viewport that fits iphone but automatically scales on iPad

Tags: iphone, html, ipad, web-applications, iphone-web-app

I'm developing a web application that also has a mobile webapp.
I currently use :

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">`

This works great for both iPhone and iPad.

My problem is that I'm using fixed size font (e.g. 18px), but on iPad I would like for it to look exactly as on the iPhone just much respectively bigger.

Is there a way for me to define the viewport in a way that will fit iPhone, and on iPad will look the same just in bigger scale? (like zooming in)?

p.s
I also don't want to stop it from working on android, which it currently does :)

The mobile webapp could be viewed here: [HocSpot Mobile](http://www.hocspot.com/mobile/mobile.htm), and the webapp here: [HocSpot](http://www.hocspot.com)

Comment: Why don't do like you do, but measuring (or guessing by user agent) the viewport's size and scaling the font-size style with the factor like: 18*currentViewPortHeight/320 ?

Comment: It is possible. but it is not an elegant solution. Many iPhone apps that run on iPad as well have a x2 / x1 options, that easily just enlarges the iphone app. this is exactly what i want for my webapp

Comment: You talk about the option to run *native* iPhone apps full screen on iPads, don't you. That might be elegant from a programmers perspective, cause there's nothing to do, but it looks dirty for the user. Best way to me seems to make you own user interface for tablets and smart phones.

Comment: I completely agree with you @Kai. What I'm trying to do here is find a temporary solution for until we create the iPad's interface. I prefer for the temporary solution to be this one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it out

http://lessframework.com/

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use CSS media queries? That will work in a UIWebView.

```
@media screen and (max-width:1024px) {
    // iPad rules
}

@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
    // iPhone rules
}
```

Then you can just style the font sizes with CSS.